# Does <script> tag affects php execution?

Tags: php

I have a PHP file with a code to increase the page views on each page visit. Summarized, it's something like this:

design.php

```
...
public function increase_views() {
    global $db;
    $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table." SET views = views + 1 
            WHERE id = {$this->id}"; 
    $db->run($sql);
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once(design.php); 
...
$design->increase_views();
echo $design->views;
?>
...
<script src="javascript/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script...
<script...
...
```

This increase_views() methods increases in 1 the view field in the database. However, each  occurrence causes an additional increment. Since I have 3  tags, the views increase 4 by 4 instead of 1 by 1. But if I REMOVE the  tags, it increases correctly (+1).

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: what are/is the code in between those script tags?

Comment: does js in  script cause browser call index.php?

Comment: Are the scripts correctly loading, or are those requests being routed to index.php?

Comment: Obligatory 'never use globals, ESPECIALLY in an OOP context' comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do those JavaScript files exist? If not, they may be redirecting to a 404 PHP page that calls your `increase_views()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the type of answer I was looking for. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't, because the script tag executes JavaScript, ECMAScript, and VBScript, which is not related to PHP. Chances are that your file does not exist. To make sure that the issue is not that your script does not exist at that location, copy your JavaScript code, and put it between two `<script>` tags like this:
`<script>
// Your javascript code here
</script>`
Also, check your JavaScript console for errors. Look here for a guide on how to bring up the console: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Good luck!